# Groovy - Compare date and Time

Tags: shell, datetime, groovy

I have two strings , which are each got from respective shell commands and are not uniformly formatted. 
Two strings obtained are as follows:

```
Date : Tue Feb 28 16:23:20 2017 -0600
Executed at : Tue Feb 28 17:24:06 EST 2017
```

EDIT: I get the above mentioned dates , one through git log and other through cat and store both in variables

First date is got through and stored in X:

```
  sh 'git log <file> | grep Date | head -n 1 > X '
```

Second date is got through below and stored in Y:

```
   sh 'cat chef-policy-release.log | grep <file> | tail -n 1 | grep -o "Executed at.*" > Y'
```

Now I wanted to pick out just date and time among that and wanted to check if executed time is after the Date value or not ?

Comment: Can you provide more contest? Do you get the dates into variables? Do you need the solution in groovy?

Comment: How do you run these commands? On a command prompt? and feed these values to groovy script? Or how do you get these date into program which you like to compare?

Comment: This is part of my groovy script. I am running it on Jenkins pipeline . I wanted to add a pre-check to compare between the two dates before a particular action is being performed.

Comment: It appears that you could trim off the left part by splitting at colon, and taking the right side. Then take what remains and parse as a date. Finally, use built-in date functions to compare the two resulting dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

```
def dateStr1 = 'Tue Feb 28 16:23:20 2017 -0600'
def dateStr2 = 'Tue Feb 28 17:24:06 EST 2017'
def pattern1 = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z"
def pattern2 = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
def date = new Date().parse(pattern1, dateStr1)
def executeDate = new Date().parse(pattern2, dateStr2)
assert date < executeDate, 'Execute Date is earlier than the date'
```

You may quickly try it online (negative test)<kbd>[Demo](https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5191425822031872)</kbd>

**EDIT: Based on OP's comment to parse the string and extract the date**
You could have applied *@GreBeardedGeek*'s parsing logic.

```
//Closure to get the date parsed
def getDate = { delimiter, dateFormat, dateStr  ->
   def dt = dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf(delimiter) + 1).trim()
   println dt
   new Date().parse(dateFormat, dt)
}

def dateStr1 = 'Date : Tue Feb 28 16:23:20 2017 -0600'
def dateStr2 = 'Executed at : Tue Feb 28 17:24:06 EST 2017'
def pattern1 = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z"
def pattern2 = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy"
def date = getDate(':', pattern1, dateStr1)
def executeDate = getDate(':', pattern2, dateStr2)
assert date < executeDate, 'Execute Date is earlier than the date'
```

**Edit#2​** can be more simplified to:

```
//Set / assign the two dates
def dateStr1 = 'Date : Tue Feb 28 16:23:20 2017 -0600'
def dateStr2 = 'Executed at : Tue Feb 28 17:24:06 EST 2017'
def getDate = { dateStr  -> Date.parse(dateStr.substring(dateStr.indexOf(':') + 1).trim()) }
assert getDate(dateStr1) < getDate(dateStr2), 'Execute Date is earlier than the date'
```

Comment: Works great !! One quick qn , I tried doing X.split(":") to try to split out left hand side Date and Executed at from the two variables, but it does not seem to work. Any other way to split it out and get the required format as u have used ?

Comment: You mean, you want me to extract date string out of `Date : Tue Feb 28 16:23:20 2017 -0600`?

Comment: Ya would be great if we could extract just "Feb 28 16:23:20 2017"  ... If not wanted to Atleast extract "Tue Feb 28 16:23:20 2017 -0600" ignoring the left hand side of "Date:"

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Worked great and accepted !

Comment: Your first example (and the console you point to) is failing with `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (String, String)`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Rao's answer, but with a function to parse the string, no need for date format strings, and without creating un-needed Date instances:

```
class DateTest{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String logDateString = args[0];
    String execDateString = args[1];

    Date logDate = parseDate(logDateString);
    Date execDate = parseDate(execDateString);

    System.out.println(execDate > logDate);
  }

  static def parseDate(String rawString) {
    String dateString = rawString.substring(rawString.indexOf(":") + 1).trim();
    new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try to use it whenever possible. As of now, went with Rao answer as it was easier to put inside groovy script. Yours too worked totally fine though.